# Periodic mySql backups

Tags: mysql

I want to periodically backup one table of my database.
I have found the mysql dump command, its working perfectly.

> mysqldump -u root -ppass example > "c:\Users\Gevindu M\Desktop"\myfirst2.sql

I want to use this command in mysql event.
How may i do it?.
for me This command only run in cmd. Its giving errors in mysql command line client and mysql work bench.why is that?...

please help me to learn how to backup periodically using mysql event.

Comment: Don't do it in a event, do it in a cronjob.

Comment: what is a cronjob. is it possible in windows

Comment: google "windows alternative for cronjob" or something like that. I'm not familiar with windows. But you can't use mysqldump inside the MySQL server. It's a separate program that accesses the server from the outside.

Comment: use windows task scheduler.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler